# Rails 4 Sidekiq cannot find the ActiveRecord Objects at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sidekiq

I am using Rails 4.2.6 and sidekiq 4.2.2. I am getting an error always that says

```
2017-02-23T07:33:23.455Z 31886 TID-ovz89uiyg WARN: {"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","queue":"mailers","args":[{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"d59ec97f-b858-4f47-aefd-c9150836d7d2","queue_name":"mailers","arguments":["UserMailer","send_password","deliver_now",{"_aj_globalid":"gid://my-app/User/85"},"http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/password/edit?config=default&reset_password_token=zBdjahtAX7w3BC3Si8Fz&redirect_url="],"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"f5dfa96df15443fc7ed2f3ce","created_at":1487832182.7783082,"enqueued_at":1487835165.842009,"error_message":"Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find User with 'id'=85","error_class":"ActiveJob::DeserializationError","failed_at":1487832182.8214011,"retry_count":7,"retried_at":1487835203.4498932}
```

I am getting the above error when sending the reset password email to the user.

I used this code for sending the mail in the background

```
UserMailer.send_password(self.id, reset_password_link).deliver_later
```

I tried the following:

```
UserMailer.send_password(self.id, reset_password_link).deliver_later(wait: 1.minutes)
```

And I also tried the after_commit callback as these document says:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3550
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/322

And I am passing ids and not the object itself. Still I am getting the above error. I updated the sidekiq version to 4.2.9 restarted the sidekiq.

Still the same error. Inside sidekiq ActiveRecord Objects cannot be found. I tried with finding very old objects inside the sidekiq, by using the byebug. But sidekiq cannot find the ActiveRecord Objects.

I am trying this for 1 day and I created the workers (say 'SendResetPasswordWorker') instead of the delay_later method. Still the same error

```
{"class":"SendResetPasswordWorker","args":[90,"http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/password/edit?config=default&reset_password_token=8xTR5enYdHDpuQg6cyPZ&redirect_url="],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"7a8a831d837d3e4f3d75d5f7","created_at":1487842213.2409139,"enqueued_at":1487842213.240968,"error_message":"Couldn't find User with 'id'=90","error_class":"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound","failed_at":1487842213.267404,"retry_count":0}2017-02-23T09:30:13.268Z 35119 TID-ow2w9e41c WARN: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=90 2017-02-23T09:30:13.268Z 35119 TID-ow2w9e41c WARN: /Users/abhilash/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/gemsets/gauge-slcsl/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find' /Users/abhilash/my-app/components/auth/app/workers/
```

I also tested it for another worker 'UserAgentWorker', another scenario but still the same error.

Anyone has any thoughts about this error? If yes please share.

Comment: Are you running Sidekiq in the same environment than your main application? For example the application might use the `production` database, while Sidekiq might run in `development` therefore read from different database.

Comment: Application and sidekiq is running in development  environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. I am using **Apartment Gem** for multi tenancy. Inside sidekiq the default schema goes back to *'public'* instead of my current schema in **postgres**. So I have to switch back to the current tenant schema each time when sidekiq run the background jobs.

Is it really needed to switch back schema all time when we run the code in background? May be we can do a setting in sidekiq, whenever it starts the job switch the schema to the current tenant. I will be checking that for the best solution. Thank you.